# Enabling PJSIP IPv6 in iOS app

Tags: ios, voip, ipv6, pjsip, arm64

I have implemented PJSIP voip app that works fine in IPv4 network. As Apple doesn't support IPv4 applications, I was trying to change the app to support IPv6. I tried to follow the instructions in https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/IPv6#IPv6Supportinpjlib but was not able to make the app work. I would like to have a clear answer for how to compile and include the PJSIP library in iOS project to support IPv6 (I want the architectures arm64 and armv7 in the compiled PJSIP library).

If somebody can give any information or links to make this possible, it will be great help.

Comment: "_As Apple doesn't support IPv4 applications..._" That is nonsense. Apple supports IPv4, but it also _requires_ IPv6 support.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. Of course I'm keeping IPv4 support also enabled in my app.

Comment: @Rounak did you find the answer for this ? I am also stuck in the same thing. Please let me know if you find any answer

Comment: @iosdeveloper I was able to enable ipv6 using the pjsip documentation. You have to follow it closely. The following links will also be helpful. https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/IPAddressChange ,  https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/IPAddressChange-2.7

Comment: @Rounak no I did not find the answer yet. I am able to enable the ipv6 into my code. But does enabling ipv6 not convert the ipv4 into ipv6.Please let me know how did you implemented pjsua_ip_change. Are you implementing it in iOS ?

Comment: @iosdeveloper I'm working on iOS. Call pjsua_transport_create for both IPv4 and IPv6. Handle transport_id of IPv6 as told in docs. I was able to do pjsua_ip_change for IPv4 networks only. I have to do IPv4 - IPv6 transitions. See PJSIP sample app also.

Comment: @Rounak Thank you for the reply. I am also working on iOS. I had implemented pjsua_transport_create.When you say create transport_id of ipv6 in docs. What I wanted to do it I wanted to make it work always for ipv4. i.e if I have 2ip(ipv6 and ipv4).I want that pjsip will always work with ipv4 and not ipv6. Please guide me

Comment: @iosdeveloper I don't think you can make PJSIP work on IPv4 when the network is IPv6. And for IPv6, keep separate code for ipv6_media_use = PJSUA_IPV6_ENABLED, nat64_opt = PJSUA_NAT64_ENABLED etc. There is separate code for ip change on IPv6 also.